# In mobile smartphone when I click Registrati the square is below icon cart

Tags: magento-1.9.4.0

In mobile smartphone when I click  Registrati the square is below icon cart

RegardsRoberto
[image]

Comment: This is the issue is related to CSS.

Comment: We need to see the code or live site to be able to help with this, it's likely a position absolute related issue.